# Is Hive's collect_list ordered?

Tags: hive, hiveql

[This page](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-Built-inAggregateFunctions(UDAF)) says of collect_list:

```
Returns a list of objects with duplicates.
```

Is that list ordered?  For example, the order of the query results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

built-in `collect_list` isn't guaranteed to be ordered, even if you do an `order by` first (even if it *did* ensure order, doing it this way is a waste of time).  Just use [brickhouse collect](https://github.com/klout/brickhouse/blob/master/src/main/java/brickhouse/udf/collect/CollectUDAF.java); it ensures the elements are ordered.

Comment: Brikhouse's collect also doesnt seem to guarantee ordering when I tried using it right now

Answer (score 4):

It's correct that `collect_list` isn't guaranteed to be ordered.  The function `sort_array` will sort the result:

```
   select a, b, sort_array(collect_list(c)) as sorted_c
   from the_table
   group by a, b
```

Comment: however, just to confirm, while this is not specified in the original question, sort_array(..) will sort by the values within the list and not another column... like in an order by...to do it by another column, it won't be pretty.