# HIVE constructing ARRAY using a column as index and an aggregate as value

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have a table which has ip, session_id, hour.
I want to aggregate this data and end up with a new table which has a record for each ip with an array of hourly aggregate of number of sessions.

To do this I started with the sub query,

```
SELECT ip, count(session_id) as sessions, hour
FROM current_table
GROUP BY ip,hour;
```

This will give me (up to) 24 records for each ip with number of sessions for a particular hour in the corresponding record. Using this sub query I want fill up an array (say hourly_sessions is the array I am working with) like,

```
hourly_sessions[hour] = sessions
```

So i will end up with an array associated with each ip and array index stands for which hour I want to check the session aggregates. If there are no sessions in a particular hour I want it to show 0.

How can I achieve this with/without using UDFs in HIVE?
My current (hacky and incomplete) approach is using something like:

```
collect_set(concat_ws(",",hour,cast(sessions) as STRING))
```

But this requires parsing the whole array each time a particular hourly aggregate is needed.

Comment: Do you need to fill in gaps in the data, so if an IP has no session for an hour, the array contains an entry with a session count of 0?

Comment: yes, that is what I would ideally want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I think you need to look at how to fill any gaps in your data. in terms of (ip, hour) pairs. One way to do this is to create a table of hours:

```
CREATE TABLE HOURS AS Select explode(Array(0,1,2...,23)) as hour;
```

Then a table of distinct IPS:

```
CREATE TABLE IPS AS SELECT distinct ip from current_table;
```

Then join them:

```
CREATE TABLE IP_HOURS AS SELECT IPS join HOURS;
```

This gives you 23 entries for each IP. Join this with your actual counts:

```
CREATE TABLE ACTUAL_COUNTS AS 
  SELECT ip, count(session_id) as sessions, hour
  FROM current_table
  GROUP BY ip,hour;

CREATE TABLE NO_GAP_COUNTS AS
    SELECT a.ip as ip, a.hour as hour, COALESCE(b.sessions, 0) as sessions
    FROM IP_HOURS a LEFT JOIN ACTUAL_COUNTS b ON (a.ip = b.ip AND a.hour = b.hour)
```

You could use this table as is, but if you really want to compact the counts per hour into an array so you have one row per ID, you could use the Brickhouse "Collect" UDF, since it will maintain the order of the sessions counts, if you order the data by ip, hour first. The built in Hive collect_set does not guarantee to preserve order.

[Is Hive's collect_list ordered?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31350150/is-hives-collect-list-ordered)

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful! This takes care of the 0 entries issue. I will have a look at Brickhouse collect for constructing the array.